# Comentário padrão para primeiras publicações que precisa de melhorias

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Gosto muito de analisar a fila de primeiras publicações para dar as boas vindas aos novos usuários da comunidade. (Mesmo na maior parte das vezes a pergunta já chegar editada e às vezes até respondida na fila).

Mas o ponto é que diversas vezes acabo colocando o mesmo comentário que já estou pensando em deixar salvo no meu pc para facilitar ao ver essas novas perguntas. Seria algo como

> Olá @OP, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua pergunta está muito ampla, o padrão da comunidade são perguntas objetivas e que possuam ao menos uma resposta correta, como pode ser visto na [help] no link [ask]. Esta sua pergunta, além de muito ampla pode dar margem a opniões. Faça um passeio pelo [tour] e depois você pode [edit] sua pergunta para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Tem de ser bem melhorada ainda, mas acredito que economizaria algumas teclas na hora de recepcionar os novos OP que ainda não conhecem os padrões da comunidade.

Poderia existir um modelo pronto, como foi feito para perguntas em outros idiomas, mas que não necessitasse de indicar a pergunta para fechar, logo de cara pois o OP ainda pode melhorar e entender a ideia.

Comment: Por ora, você pode adicionar esse à [lista de enlatados da comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/coment%C3%A1rios-enlatados-para-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-comuns). Aliás, foi você que comentou que o script que coloca o link "auto" não funciona mais? Deve ter sido por causa de mudanças no código do site.

Comment: Não conhecia a funcionalidade. Obrigado pelo toque. Vou dar uma olhada amanhã e adicionar lá.

Comment: @bfavaretto fui eu que disse que o "auto" não funciona comigo agora.